# How to reshape a tensor and obtain the first dimension in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have a tensor. Lets say its dimension is [2, 999]. How to reshape it to [999, 2] and obtain the first dimension, i.e., 999 in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here's how you can do it:

Btw tensor objects dont have a reshape function u have to call it as such with the tf.reshape function

```py
import tensorflow as tf 
tensor = tf.range(999 * 2) # create a tensor
reshaped_tensor = tf.reshape(tensor, (2, 999))

# this doesn't work
tensor = tensor.reshape(999, 2)
```

U can switch axis with the transpose command since u have the same dimensions

```py
switched_axis = tf.transpose(tensor) # assuming tensor has a shape of 999, 2
```

To print the first dimensions

```py
print(tensor.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape:

```
new_tensor = tensor.reshape((999,2))
```

Find first dimension:

```
first_dimension = tensor.shape[0]
```